# Own function and Utils package

Tags: python, function

I trying to use ready-made functions from the package `IneqPy` below you can see function and data.
The function is also described in this link https://mmngreco.github.io/IneqPy/_modules/ineqpy/inequality.html#concentration

```
# Import libraries

    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    # from .statistics import mean
    # from . import utils
    import utils
    import stats
    
    # Functions

    def concentration(income, weights=None, data=None, sort=True):
        """Calculate concentration's index.
    
        This function calculate the concentration index, according to the notation
        used in [Jenkins1988]_ you can calculate the:
    
        C_x = 2 / x · cov(x, F_x)
        if x = g(x) then C_x becomes C_y
    
        when there are taxes:
    
        y = g(x) = x - t(x)
    
        Parameters
        ----------
        income : array-like
        weights : array-like
        data : pandas.DataFrame
        sort : bool
            If true, will sort the values.
    
        Returns
        -------
        concentration : array-like
    
        References
        ----------
        Jenkins, S. (1988). Calculating income distribution indices
        from micro-data. National Tax Journal. http://doi.org/10.2307/41788716
        """
        # TODO complete docstring
    
        # check if DataFrame is passed, if yes then extract variables else make a
        # copy
        income, weights = utils.extract_values(data, income, weights)
        if weights is None:
            weights = utils.not_empty_weights(weights, like=income)
        # if sort is true then sort the variables.
        if sort:
            income, weights = utils._sort_values(income, weights)
    
        if weights.ndim == 2:
            weights = np.squeeze(weights, axis=1)
    
        if income.ndim == 2:
            income = np.squeeze(income, axis=1)
    
        # main calc
        f_x = utils.normalize(weights)
        F_x = f_x.cumsum(axis=0)
        mu = np.sum(income * f_x)
        cov = np.cov(income, F_x, rowvar=False, aweights=f_x)[0, 1]
        return 2 * cov / mu
```

After executing the above command I tried to implement these functions on this dataset explained below.

```
data = { 
            'income': list(range(1, 100))
           }    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['income'])
```

Dataset titled `df` only has one column and I tried to implement the function above.But unfortunately, here I face with several problems. Namely first problem is everything that came utils package can not be executed e.g( utils.extract_values, utils.not_empty_weights, utils._sort_values, utils.normalize). I already have installed `utils==1.0.1` and don't what is problem.

So can anybody help how to fix the problem with `utils package` and execute the above function with this line of command?

```
concentration(df['income'])
```

At the moment I can execute this function but with loaded package IneqPy and with this line of code I receive this results 0.33, but I want to have this with above described functions.

```
ineqpy.inequality.concentration(df['income'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [contents](https://github.com/mmngreco/IneqPy/tree/master/src/ineqpy) of the `IneqPy` package, you'll see that there's a file named [`utils.py`](https://github.com/mmngreco/IneqPy/tree/master/src/ineqpy/utils.py). That's the one that's supposed to be imported. Uninstall the `utils` package you installed and the code should work.

<sup>It should work anyway, but uninstalling it wouldn't hurt.</sup>